# .Net core EF, saving records to many-to-many type table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, many-to-many

I am new to EF and .Net core and I'm having trouble with many-to-many relationship in my project. I used microsoft documentation to setup the relationship, but i have trouble inserting any data. Project is a kanban board and i am trying to set up relations between users and tasks. Both of them already exist. The goal is to have a table with userId and taskId. Here are my models:

KanbanTask Model:

```
public class KanbanTask : Entity
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required] 
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int ProgressStatus { get; set; }
        public List<UserTask> UserTask { get; set; }
    }
```

User Model:

```
public class User : Entity
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public List<UserTask> UserTask { get; set; }
    }
```

Entity Model:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

UserTaskModel:

```
public class UserTask
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int KanbanTaskId { get; set; }
        public KanbanTask KanbanTask { get; set; }
    }
```

My DbContex:

```
public DbSet<KanbanTask> KanbanTasks { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserTask>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.KanbanTaskId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserTask>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.UserTask)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserTask>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.KanbanTask)
            .WithMany(t => t.UserTask)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.KanbanTaskId);
    }
}
```

My function in service:

```
 public async Task<ResultDTO> AssignTaskToUser(int taskId, int userId)
        {
            var result = new ResultDTO()
            {
                Response = null
            };
            try
            {
                var user = await _repo.GetSingleEntity(x => x.Id == userId);
                var kanbanTask = await _taskrepo.GetSingleEntity(y => y.Id == taskId);
                if (user != null && kanbanTask != null)
                {
                    var usertask = new UserTask()
                    {
                        KanbanTaskId = taskId,
                        UserId = userId
                    };
                    kanbanTask.UserTask.Add(usertask);
                    user.UserTask.Add(usertask); 
                    await _repo.Patch(user);
                }
                else
                    result.Response = "Task or user not found";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                result.Response = e.Message;
                return result;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

My repository:

```
public async Task Patch(T entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Update(entity);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
```

Comment: What version of EF and .Net Core are you using?

Comment: I don't see a PK in this line of code `.HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });` Your table needs a PK to insert into it  with EF.

Comment: You just need to add the UserTask to the change tracker and SaveChanges.  You don't even have to have the User and Task entities on-hand.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft How can I do it? My repository was generic type, so i made UserTask model to Inheritance the entity model. Then i used  await _usertaskrepo.Add(usertask); to try to add the data to database. It kind of worked, but the Id of the UserTask objects in the base remains 0 to all objects. It also didnt add any changes to User and KanbanTask (the Lists with UserTask type)

Comment: @Train I am using .Net core 3.1 and EF 3.1.2. How can i set PK in this situation? Should it be UserTask id?

Comment: Add  a UserTaskID to the entity and update the database through migration commands.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I just realized you had a composite key set up so my initial comment was wrong. @DavidBrowne-Microsoft is correct.  Follow his answer but add the `DbSet<UserTask>` you never added that to your context.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
var usertask = new UserTask()
                    {
                        KanbanTaskId = taskId,
                        UserId = userId
                    };
db.UserTasks.Add(usertask);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What is "db" in this context? Do I have to import my AppDbContext and DbSet (same ones i use in repository to save changes)? Is there a way to move those 2 lines of code to repository instead of service?

Comment: Upvote,  but this doesn't work, he doesn't have a `dbset` for UserTask. He has to add it to his context.

Comment: Yes there should be a dbset for UserTask, or you have to call `db.Set<UserTask>()`.  The UserTask is an Entity in the model, as EF Core doesn't support Many-to-Many without a linking entity.

Comment: @IgorCzeszejko-Sochacki `db` is your DbContext subtype.  You've apparently got it hidden away behind a some sort of generic repository.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to is to make sure that your middle entity (UserTask) always saves the Keys of both entities so I strongly suggest to add that logic in UserTask constructor.

```
public class UserTask
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int KanbanTaskId { get; set; }
    public KanbanTask KanbanTask { get; set; }

 public UserTask() { }

 public UserTask(User user, KanbanTask kanbanTask) 
 {
    KanbanTask = kanbanTask;
    KanbanTaskId = kanbanTask.Id;
    User = user;
    UserId = userId;
  }
}
```

//

```
                var usertask = new UserTask(user, kanbanTask);
                kanbanTask.UserTask.Add(usertask);
                user.UserTask.Add(usertask); 
                await _repo.Patch(user);
```

//

I have wrote an example for this common problem. Here https://github.com/salsita18/ManyToManyNetCore you can check the approach I took, using a single generic MiddleEntity class.
I also added it to nuget in order to reuse it, but you can just make your own implementation following the pattern